# Magento custom cache clear by regex

Tags: cache, regex, cache-tag

Is it possible in Magento to allow for cache to be cleared in a custom code by using regular expression to target cache tags?

The scenario I have is I am know of a list of cache tags I will be cleaning but they will each have a different suffix on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup your tags and keys correctly in your custom module, calling

`Mage::app()->cleanCache();`

Should do what you need, without the ugly regex.

More details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589947/clear-magento-cache-based-on-key-pattern
- http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/improving-the-file-cache-backend/